# Why does find_packages behavior depend on import of pip package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have following project structure:

```
prog
  __init__.py
tests
  subpak
    __init__.py
  __init__.py
run1.py
run2.py
```

run1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from setuptools import find_packages


for i in sorted(find_packages(exclude=['tests'])):
    print(i)
```

run2.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pip
from setuptools import find_packages


for i in sorted(find_packages(exclude=['tests'])):
    print(i)
```

The rest of the files are empty. Environment - Debian testing. python 3.5.

run1.py output:

```
$ python3 run1.py 
prog
```

run2.py output:

```
$ python3 run2.py 
prog
tests.subpak
```

That is, when `find_packages` is imported after `pip`, it no longer excludes sub-packages of excluded package. Why is this happening and what kind of mechanisms are involved in this peculiar behavior?

edit:
It appears that pip or some of its dependencies are changing syspath, and `setuptools` modules are different. Run1:

```
<module 'setuptools' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
```

Run2:

```
<module 'setuptools' from '/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py'>
```

Comment: Silly question: why are you importing `pip` in the first place?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the code above is demo of the issue I encountered while working with actual setup.py script, which makes use of some pip functions: `from pip.req import parse_requirements`

Comment: What version of `pip` and what version of `setuptools`? I can't reproduce this with 8.1.2 and setuptools 27.2.0 I get the *second output* for that one.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Python 3.5.2+ (default, Sep 22 2016, 12:18:14), setuptools 28.0.0, pip 8.1.2

Comment: Either way, the *first* output is incorrect, since the `tests` filter won't match the `test.subpack` name. Use `['tests*']` or `['tests', 'tests.*']` for that. It looks as if your `find_packages` there is broken, and `pip` shadows the wrong import.

Comment: What does `import setuptools; print(setuptools, find_packages)` produce for either run?

Comment: @MartijnPieters true, I've already switched to `['tests', 'tests\\.*']` even before posting this question, and it solved my initial issue; however, I'd still like to find out why it happens.

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all; I upgraded to setuptools 28.6.1 now and I still see the second output with and without `pip`.

Comment: `$ python3 run1.py: <module 'setuptools' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'> <bound method PackageFinder.find of <class 'setuptools.PackageFinder'>>`, `$ python3 run2.py: <module 'setuptools' from '/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py'> <bound method PackageFinder.find of <class 'setuptools.PackageFinder'>>`, that is `pip` indeed changes `sys.path` - it prepends few paths: http://funkyimg.com/i/2iFFV.png. Post it as answer and I will mark it as correct one. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add that detail to your question? `pip` imports `wheel` support, so now you are finding a different setuptools version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip` imports `wheel` support, and this appears to unlock a wheel you didn't know you had:

```
<module 'setuptools' from '/usr/share/python-wheels/setuptools-20.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/setuptools/__init__.py'>
```

Without the wheel you are importing a system-wide `setuptools` version:

```
<module 'setuptools' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py'>
```

This version appears to be broken, because `test.subpack` is *supposed* to be included (filter it out by adding `'tests.*'` to the `exclude` list).

Comment: Thanks. Found a line in pip source code which prepends wheel to sys.path: https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/pip/_vendor/__init__.py#L58